# jQuery change image position

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I need your help.

I want to build a table has 2 columns labeled X and Y, an input field in each column and a change button, when user click the button it jQuery function would check if the fields are empty, if they are the function would put the default values in the offset({left: x, top:y}) which is defined in jquery header, if the fields are not empty it would take the values from the fields and change the position of the image.

So the position of the image would change each time the user change the values of the fields.

Thanx in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JS fiddle with a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/UKRD8/14/

Just make sure you put in the 'px' after you enter the number for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="position:relative; z-index:9;">
        <tr>
            <td>X:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtX" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Y:</td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtY" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input id="btnUpdate" type="button" value="Update" onclick="updateCords()" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/160px-Smiley.svg.png" style="position:absolute; z-index:1;" />
  </div>  

<script>
    function updateCords() {
        var x = $('#txtX').val();
        var y = $('#txtY').val();

        if (x === '') { x = 0 }
        if (y === '') { y = 0 }

        $('#img').css({ 'left': x + 'px', 'top': y + 'px' });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you but I want three rows, each row would change an image position and just one button, thank you for your help